# What are the settings for Appium setup on Mac

Tags: node.js, automation, environment-variables, homebrew, appium-ios

I am trying to setup mac automation machine for Appium and having few confusions for setup(Background is Test automation ).I have downloaded Jdk,Eclipse IDE for mac,xcode and homebrew + node via homebrew.
I have setup env variable for JDK in the .bash_profile.However i am not sure that if i need to add env variable for the Node as well somehow (I installed Node via homebrew) like in case of windows.
Also i wanted to understand what all properties that i need to mention in mac .bash_profile.
I installed appium with npm install -g appium .
Also can anyone advice me how can i open my xcode simulator programmatically(Basically where should i update my .app path)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed `node` properly, run `node -v` in terminal: you should get its version. Do the same with `npm`.

Then install appium-doctor to check appium env: `npm install -g appium-doctor`

To check if env setup done properly for iOS, you need to run:
`appium-doctor --ios`

If there are no red marks => you are done, otherwise fix the error points (variables, path, etc.)

Appium will **start simulator automatically** before test, just make sure you set in capabilities the one that is supported by your XCode version.

Answer (score 0):

1. First we need to check that which xcode version is compatible with our Mac OS, Please use this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode .
2. Then Download the Xcode ( https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ ). After installation move the xCode to application folder
   Then we need to execute this below query

   `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

   To check the Xcode path below is the query

   `xcode-select -p`
3. Download java 8 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
4. Download Eclipse for Java Developers and install it,from this link
   http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
5. Download node js and install it https://nodejs.org/en/download/
6. Install Homebrew :
   Open terminal then run this command `/usr/bin/ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL` https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   To check the version brew — version
7. Install Carthage then run this command 
   `brew install carthage
   brew install libimobiledevice –HEAD
   npm install -g ios-deploy ( make sure you have Xcode installed first )
   brew install ideviceinstaller`
8. Run

   `Install appiumnpm install -g appium
   npm install wd
   npm install appium-doctor -g`

To starting using Appium and the Appium inspector for iOS devices you must first install the webdriveragent app to your iOS device.

9. `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`
10. `mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle`
11. bash Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d
12. Download the Xcode web driver project from git hub from below link
    https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent
13. Go to the below location and open Xcode project

    `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`
14. Download appium Desktop https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.2
15. Get the certificate from the developer Distribution certificateDev certificate Open those certificate and add to keychain
16. In Xcode change the bundle identifier name/team/signing details

Then add all the capabilities in appium and save it

```
{
 “platformName”: “iOS”,
 “deviceName”: “iPhone 5”,
 “platformVersion”: “11.0”,
 “app”: “/Users/sasmitabehara/Downloads/abc.ipa”,
 “automationName”: “XCUITest”,
 “udid”: “8a25b3a9b2f312dfb9b8492827d7feeded7a9afa”,
 “noReset”: true,
 “appiumVersion”: “1.8.1”,
 “agentPath”: “/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj”,
 “bootStrapPath”: “/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent”,
 “xCodeSigningId”: “iphone Developer”
}
```

Once everything is ready then run web driver agent, once u got build succeeded msg then Open Appium and open the saved capabilities ,Start the server.

Thank You :)